# Тормозит CSS-анимация

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, анимация, css-animation

Суть вопроса в следующем. На сайте есть sidebar (выезжающее справа меню), анимация которого построена на CSS-transitions. В неактивном состоянии sidebar имеет следующий код:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
opacity: 0;
width: 300px;
background: #fff;
z-index: 9999;
-o-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
transform: translate(300px, 0px);
```

в активном состоянии к нему добавляется класс с таким кодом:

```
transform: translate(0px, 0px);
opacity: 1;
```

Проблема в том, что периодически наблюдаются тормоза при открытии/закрытии меню. Профайлер Google Chrome толком не дает никакой информации по причине подвисаний. На кадр анимации уходит всего 1-3 ms, но FPS может упасть до 15-20 кадров. Тормоза вылазят периодически (в эти моменты тормозит вся анимация), из закономерностей заметил, что они часто появляются в периоды простоя (когда на сайте не совершается никаких действий 20-30 секунд).

Полагаю, возможная причина отчасти в самом железе/ПО (хотя оно шустрое), но хотелось бы устранить подвисания. Отсюда вопросы:

1. В чем причина подобных тормозов, кто сталкивался с этим?
2. Какие решения Вы использовали, чтобы сделать анимацию более плавной?

P.S. `will-change: transform;` не помогает, т.к. браузер и без него всё выносит в отдельный слой.

Comment: отчасти помогло более конкретное определение свойств у transition. В данном примере вместо "transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;" указал "transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out, opacity 250ms ease-in-out;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добиться более плавной анимации помог комплекс следующих действий:

1. Точное указание property у transition (т.е. вместо "transition: all" указываем конкретное свойство с которым производится анимация).
2. Использование при JS манипуляции с классами не classList, а className. Переход на это решение позволил добиться реального прогресса в плавности анимации. В частности, это решение подсказал VK, там используется такая же схема. Метод className входит в DOM Core (level 2), имеет практически полную совместимость со всеми браузерами, а также более эффективно обрабатывается браузерными движками с минимальными задержками.

Answer (score 3):

- Уберите свойство `opacity: 1;`. Во-первых, оно бесполезно в данном
  случае, а во вторых – именно оно может влиять на FPS. Если же вам
  действительно необходимо скрывать блок, замените `opacity` на
  `visibility`.
- В `transition` нужно указать именно то свойство, которое будет анимироваться – вместо `transition: all .25s` производительнее будет `transition: transform .25s`. Если у вас несколько свойств, которые нужно анимировать, можно написать так: `transition: transform .25s, opacity .25s`.

К примеру, [здесь](http://1000.tech/ru) реализовал подобное меню и работает без лагов.

Comment: такая же проблема с 1000.tech. при первом открытии все идеально, но стоит некоторое время повисеть на сайте, как появляются небольшие урывки при открытии/закрытии меню.

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov попробуйте затестировать меню в инкогнито режиме с единственной вкладкой. Может у вас какие-то плагины кушают память?

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov соглашусь с соседним комментарием. Скорее всего что-то уже на вашей стороне.

Comment: @YozhEzhi да, есть веские подозрения, что проблема именно на моей стороне, но точно не узнаешь, пока не выгрузишь проект на продакшн. полагаю дело даже не в браузерах (тормозит как в Chrome, так и в IE), а в чем-то на уровне взаимодействия с ОС (на ноуте много специфического ПО для разработки, различных библиотек и программ, которые тесно работают с ОС). другой вопрос, что хочется найти решения и для таких ситуаций, чтобы сохранить плавность анимации.

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov чтобы лечить - нужно установить диагноз :). Попробуйте локально потестировать проект на другом ПК. Заведомо без всякого специфического ПО. Ибо в вашем коде - никакого криминала нет.

Comment: @YozhEzhi отчасти помогло более конкретное определение свойств у transition. В данном примере вместо "transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;" указал "transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out, opacity 250ms ease-in-out;".

Answer (score -1):

opacity - Вам действительно не нужно. 
Лучший вариант для плавности анимации это использование translate3D - особенно хорошо работает на моб. устройствах. 
Вот здесь можно глянуть скорость загрузки: 
http://jsperf.com/translate3d-vs-xy/28